# GetExports<T, TMetaDataView> in MEF returns no elements with AllowMultiple = True

Tags: c#, export, mef, containers, ioc-container

I'm not sure how MEF works. I create a custom attribute with `AllowMultiple=true`. And here it is:

```
public interface IQuestionFactoryMetadataView
{
    IQuestionFactoryMetadata[] Metadatas { get; }
}

public interface IQuestionFactoryMetadata
{
    Levels Difficulty { get; }
    int Quantity { get; }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ExportQuestionFactoryAttribute : ExportAttribute, IQuestionFactoryMetadata
{
    public ExportQuestionFactoryAttribute(Type type, Levels difficulty, int quantity)
        : base(type.Namespace, typeof(IQuestionFactory))
    {
        this.Difficulty = difficulty;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Levels Difficulty { get; private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }
}

// 
[ExportQuestionFactory(typeof(NonConcreteQuestionFactory), Levels.Beginner, 10)]
[ExportQuestionFactory(typeof(NonConcreteQuestionFactory), Levels.Medium, 20)]
[ExportQuestionFactory(typeof(NonConcreteQuestionFactory), Levels.Expert, 30)]
[ExportQuestionFactory(typeof(NonConcreteQuestionFactory), Levels.Master, 40)]
public class NonConcreteQuestionFactory : QuestionTemplateFactory
{
    ...
}
```

If I use weakly typed Metadata, my export is suddenly satisfied:

```
        var exports = container.GetExports<IQuestionFactory, IDictionary<string, object>>(typeof(PEMDAS.Core.TimesTables.WorksheetTemplate).Namespace);
```

But if I use strongly typed, my exports variable is empty.

```
        var exports = container.GetExports<IQuestionFactory, IQuestionFactoryMetadataView>(typeof(PEMDAS.Core.TimesTables.WorksheetTemplate).Namespace);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see QuestionFactoryMetadataView can you show that type?

Does

```
var exports = container.GetExports<IQuestionFactory, IQuestionFactoryMetadata>(...)
```

work?

Comment: Sorry, it was an interface.. I was testing. With IQuestionFactoryMetadata interface does not work